# Very simple code using $.post of jquery is showing the entire code instead of the echo

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

The code is supposed to change the writing on the div from "Click here" to "hello", but instead, it show the entire code of the php document.

HTML:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="target">
      Click here
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="jcode.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Javascript:

```
$( "#target" ).click(function() {
  $.post(
        'test.php', {name:"Donald"}, 
        function(data){
            $('#target').html(data);
        }
    );
});
```

PHP:

```
<$php
if(isset($_POST['name'])){
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    echo $name;
}
echo 'hello';
$>
```

Comment: Are you running this on a web server?

Comment: Which server are you using? Something's wrong with your **server configuration**, not your PHP code.

Comment: Im using wamp server running on local host.

Answer (score 3):

`<$php` and `$?` are not PHP tags, `<?php` and `?>` are. Use the folowing.

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['name'])){
        $name = $_POST['name'];
        echo $name;
    }
    echo 'hello';
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Force php to return data in json format and of course the relevant header so they can understand each other really well. Try using this method:

PHP

```
<?php header('Content-Type: application/json');

    if(isset($_POST['name']))
    {
        $name = $_POST['name'];

        $response = [
            'name' => $name
        ];
    }

    echo json_encode($response);
?>
```

Javascript:

```
$( "#target" ).click(function() {
    $.post('test.php', {name:"Donald"}, 
        function(data){
            $('#target').html(data.name);
        }
    );
});
```